# Equivalente a DESCryptoServiceProvider en Java

Tags: java, c#

En C# utilizo el siguiente objeto:

```
DESCryptoServiceProvider dESCryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
```

¿Existe algún equivalente en Java?

Comment: Hola @albetro. Por favor provee más información en tu pregunta. Tal como se encuentra ahora, no se entiende qué necesitas hacer y cuál es el problema que enfrentas.

Comment: hola gracias por responder en si ocupo crear un metodo con la misma encritacion en c# y en java el de c# ya lo tengo pero el de java no le encuentro como hacerlo

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no encuentas? ¿Cuál es el problema en sí? Si lo que necesitas es encriptar contenido de algo en Java, busca un tutorial para serializar, donde te indican las librerías que deben haber en tu aplicación, los tipos de algoritmos de encriptación, si quieres que sea de una vía (no se puede desencriptar) o doble vía (se puede desencriptar), las llaves, el salt y más conceptos. Tratar de traducir código de un lenguaje a otro ciegamente no resolverá tu problema.

Comment: hola la función es encriptar una palabra en c# y el resultado meterlo a java y que me la desencripte

Comment: Entonces lo que buscas es desencriptar en Java. Busca un tutorial al respecto.

Comment: si lose y lo tengo haciendo toda la semana he encontrado muchos pero no logro implementarlos asi tal y cual, en si tengo dos metodos en c# con base 64 y ocupo hacer dos metodos igual en java que puedan encriptar y desencriptar los resultados en ambos aplicaciones

Comment: @albetrocota Por lo que comentas parece que la encriptación en C# ya la tienes hecha. ¿Puedes poner el programa en C# que encripta? Quitando del programa todo lo que no tenga que ver con la encriptación; deja lo mínimo para que el programa compile y, por ejemplo, imprima la cadena encriptada o la guarde en un fichero. Es decir, te pido un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Hola no entiendo bien que deseas con ello, imagino que hacer un cifrado simétrico, para el caso de java, cuenta con la api  Crypto. Te dejo la documentación oficial para que te ds un mayor contexto,

[Crypto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html)

```
String llaveSimetrica = "key";

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(llaveSimetrica.getBytes(), "AES");
      Cipher cipher;
      try {
       cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    ....{
```

este es mi metodo en c#

```
public static string Encrypt(string strText){
        string base64String;

       byte[] numArray = new byte[] { 18, 52, 86, 120, 144, 171, 205, 239 };
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("%#@?,:*&");
            byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);
            DESCryptoServiceProvider dESCryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, dESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, numArray), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(bytes1, 0, (int)bytes1.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
        catch{base64String = "";}
        return base64String;
    }
```

Comment: Tengo un metodo en c#  y necesito crear un metodo en java que replique el cifrado de c#  ,solo que no se la sintaxis de java soy nuevo por eso quiero saber como puedo implementar este es el metodo en c#: